# How to save generated image from (imagecreatefromjpeg) to SERVER with .jpg extension

Tags: php

I have a php script generating an image, but I can't save it as jpg... instead it has a .php file extension

I tried using 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" .jpeg"');

but it is not working

Answer (score 4):

You can Use `imagejpeg($image,$filename)`

```
<?php
// Create a blank image and add some text
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);

// Save the image as 'simpletext.jpg'
imagejpeg($im, 'simpletext.jpg');

// Free up memory
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

imagejpeg function will Output image to browser or file